# Compare unordered DataFrame compare value based on comparison and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames (PreServices, PostServices) each DataFrame contains Windows services and their running status at a given time.

How does Data look like?

1. there is no order of how services names are listed
2. PostServices may or not have Names that are in PreServices
3. PostServices may have Names that are not in PreServices

I want to create a new column in PreServices named 'final status' and its values should be such that:

1. for each Name in PreService if Name in PostServices and State are the same 'final status' == True
2. for each Name in PreService if Name in PostServices and State are the not same  'final status' = PostServices['State']
3. for each Name in PreService Not in PostService 'final status' = False

> PreServices

```
                           Name    State
0                         VMTools  Running
1                             LSM  Running
2                        macmnsvc  Running
3    VMwareCAFManagementAgentHost  Running
4                          sppsvc  Stopped
5               LanmanWorkstation  Running
6                          MpsSvc  Running
7                           MSDTC  Running
8                            MSMQ  Running
```

> PostServices

```
                             Name    State
0                        macmnsvc  Running
1                             LSM  Running
2                         VMTools  Stopped
3    VMwareCAFManagementAgentHost  Running
4                          sppsvc  Stopped
5               LanmanWorkstation  Running
6                          MpsSvc  Running
7                             xlp  Running
```

> Output

```
                           Name    State     final status
0                         VMTools  Running   Stopped
1                             LSM  Running   True
2                        macmnsvc  Running   True
3    VMwareCAFManagementAgentHost  Running   True
4                          sppsvc  Stopped   True
5               LanmanWorkstation  Running   True
6                          MpsSvc  Running   True
7                           MSDTC  Running   False
8                            MSMQ  Running   False
```

Comment: can you add your expected output

Comment: If the solution posted below solves your problem, please feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet will get your desired output:

```
def create_final_status(row):
    if row['Name'] in PostServices['Name'].values:
        if row['State'] == PostServices[PostServices['Name'] == row['Name']]['State'].item():
            return True
        else:
            return PostServices[PostServices['Name'] == row['Name']]['State']
    else:
        return False

PreServices['final status'] = PreServices.apply(lambda row: create_final_status(row), axis = 1)
```

The PreServices Dataframe will now look like this:

```
+----+------------------------------+---------+----------------+
|    | Name                         | State   | final status   |
|----+------------------------------+---------+----------------|
|  0 | VMTools                      | Running | Stopped        |
|  1 | LSM                          | Running | True           |
|  2 | macmnsvc                     | Running | True           |
|  3 | VMwareCAFManagementAgentHost | Running | True           |
|  4 | sppsvc                       | Stopped | True           |
|  5 | LanmanWorkstation            | Running | True           |
|  6 | MpsSvc                       | Running | True           |
|  7 | MSDTC                        | Running | False          |
|  8 | MSMQ                         | Running | False          |
+----+------------------------------+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: in my case i wanted to return,  return post[post['Name'] == row['Name']]['State'].item()   else it would also return the index.